# MySQL append , prefix a range of numbers with 0

Tags: mysql

I have around a few thousand rows with which contain 3 digit numbers starting with 100 and ranging to 199 which i need to prefix with 0. There are also thousands of other numbers 4 digit numbers as well which i don't want to change.

I need find all the 3 digit numbers in the range and prefix only those ranging from 100 -199 with a 0 so as they are 4 digits eg 100 > 0100 , 104 > 0104 and so on.
Also these numbers may step eg 110 next is 124.

Is there a way I can do this using SQL? as i don't fancy changing these manually!

Many Thanks

Comment: Is there a scripting language you are using?

Comment: Im using PHP5 and using MySQL Front.

Comment: Check that the field is a CHAR, as adding a zero to the left of a number and saving it to the db will only remove it again  (numbers don't start with a zero)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is best done with a programming language. That said, here's a SQL query that will update all the existing numbers:

```
UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = right(concat('0000',fieldName), 4) WHERE length(fieldName) < 4
```

Comment: Thanks cpharmston, you would think looking at that it would just replace everything < 4 with 0000. But it doesn't it retains the original number and works great-  thanks, you saved me a lot of time. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

The [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function is what you are looking for. You can use this in your query to pad the numbers on the fly.

```
SELECT LPAD(CONVERT(num AS CHAR), 4, '0') FROM tbl WHERE num > 99 AND num < 200
```

If you prefer to do this on the script side, [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) will do the same in php.

Comment: Thanks Dane the Sane. Ill try that as well but the above seems to work ok.